# Facing issue while converting 18 digit double value to long

Tags: java, double, decimal, long-integer

I am receiving double value [18-19 digits] as input to my method and I have to convert it to long value.
I have no interest in handling the decimal part of input as input will always be ending with .0

For example ,
input will be like

double val1 = 1000000000000007403.0;
double val2 = 2223372036854774845.0;

I tried below code,

In below code example,
my input is val1 and val2.

```
public static void main (String args[]){
        
    double val1 = 1000000000000007403.0;   // input
    double val2 = 2223372036854774845.0;   // input

    Double double1 = Double.valueOf(val1);
    Double double2 = Double.valueOf(val2);
        
    long val1Long = double1.longValue();
    long val2Long = double2.longValue();
    System.out.println(val1Long);
    System.out.println(val2Long);   
}
```

But it is returning wrong output.

Output:

1000000000000007424
2223372036854774784

Expected output:

1000000000000007403
2223372036854774845

I am attaching the debug screenshot of method as well. [image]
I am facing this issue whenever my double value is greater than 14-15 digits.

Comment: You will! A double mantissa of 53 bits can only accommodate at most 16 decimal digits and some environments restrict it to 15 in the user interface. A long double with its 64bit mantissa is your best choice if you need to faithfully preserve all the digits. The input has been converted to the closest double precision number that the machine can represent.

Comment: *// input* Is that really the case? You show a main method

Comment: IMO you should receive the double value as String then return as long.

Comment: @g00se,
Thanks for the response. I just wrote this code as reference, in actual case i am receiving the input from some other  application which is sending double values like these [ val1 & val2].

Comment: @moyu-sharo, Thanks for the response. 
receiving input asString is not pssible in my case

Comment: Pity. I was going to make the same point as @moyu-sharo

Comment: @MartinBrown, Thanks for the response Martin.
 you mentioned A long double with its 64bit mantissa is the best choice,  can you please provide a referance how to implement it?
if you have any link to it or any kind of reference.

Comment: In Java I think double is the longest floating point native format that you have so your best bet is to read your input as a string and then store it as a long integer (64bits where it will fit ). If the other application is sending you a double in binary form then the precision has already been lost in that conversion. Other languages like GCC have native support for 80bit FP (which was part of the x87 legacy numeric coprocessor) and a few compilers have quad precision 128bit FP support.

Comment: When you receive `double` values from another application, that other application never passed the value `1000000000000007403.0` to your application as that value doesn’t exist in the `double` value space. So your application is working correctly. I don’t understand why you discuss hypothetical types like “long double”. Even if it existed, it wouldn’t help, if you can’t change the other application.

Comment: @Holger, Thanks for the response.
You are right about input, its not 1000000000000007403.0 but 1.00000000000000742E18,  however issue was the other application is fetching the data(1000000000000007403.0) from some Database as double value and sending the value(1.00000000000000742E18).
Thanks for the clarification, I think i need to ask the application to enhance the way of reading data and ask them to send as String.